# Should I use the same font size between phone, tablet and desktop?

Tags: font, font-sizes

When making a responsive stylesheet.  Is it better to keep the text sizes the same pixel size.  Note I am using the following to normalize the sizes across.  Also for the purpose of this question I'm limiting to a single type-face for simplicity.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Or does it make sense to have different sizes as a norm.

e.g. on mobile use `14px` default body text size vs tablet which has `16px` font size and desktop which has `20px` font size

vs

`16px` default body text size regardless of display.

From a technical point of view keeping one size makes it easier to manage the design rather than having altering CSS font sizes between devices.

Related:

- [Smaller font sizes on smaller screen devices](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/131260/smaller-font-sizes-on-smaller-screen-devices)
- https://ia.net/topics/responsive-typography-the-basics a lot of words but I think the net of it is that it should be the different.
- https://blog.logrocket.com/using-em-vs-rem-css/ also uses device specific base font size BUT at least everything is relative due to the use of `rem` therefore making it easy to code as well.

Comment: Generally, using `px` for font sizes is considered a bad practice; the better practice is to use `em`. This also accommodates people who need to resize text. It also potentially allows you to use a single style sheet for all sizes of device screen, since the size of the em can be set by the device/device user.

Comment: I don't think React-Native supports `em` but it does allow scaling from px.

Comment: It appears to support the relative-em (`rem`); see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628677/react-native-responsive-font-size). I don't have access to full documentation, but support for the `rem` suggests that it should also support the `em`.

Comment: Also recommended reading: https://blog.logrocket.com/using-em-vs-rem-css/

Comment: Please don't follow any articles on CSS more than a few years ago. CSS is changing very quickly. Now, one could define the main font styles, then use calculations to adjust type according to size of screen or size of containing element.

Answer (score 1):

As other posters in here, I would suggest this is why em/rem are options. px is for defined screen real estate, if you are putting importance on several different screen sizes, you need to use something more appropriate.

Trying to create different px values for each screen size is an outdated roundabout way of getting the job done and leads to more elements that you have to keep in check as the product/design evolves. You already need to worry about these values between the headers, paragraphs and subtitles you use.